# Scala issue about option.contains()

Tags: scala, functional-programming

It seems option`.contains()` does not always work as expected. I have the following code:

```
case class Person (name: String, nickName: Option[String])

val people = Seq(Person("Ned", Some("d")), Person("Alex", None))
val suspects = Map("c" -> 1, "d" -> 2)

val result1 = people.filter(_.nickName.contains(suspects.contains(_)))
val result2 = people.filter{ p =>
    p.nickName.contains{ n =>
        suspects.contains(n)
    }
}
    
println(result1)
println(result2)
```

You might expect `result1` and `result2` contains a person, but they are actually empty. Why?

It turns out the follow code works:

```
val result3 = people.filter{ _.nickName match {
        case Some(n) => suspects.contains(n)
        case None => false
    }
}
val result4 = people.filter( _.nickName.map(suspects.contains).getOrElse(false))
val result5 = people.filter( _.nickName.fold(false)(suspects.contains))

println(result3)
println(result4)
println(result5)
```

I have tried on both Scala 2.12 and 2.13, and results are the same. Why `nickName.contains` does not work?

Comment: As I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#contains[A1%3E:A](elem:A1):Boolean) is your friend. You are a bit confused about what `contains` do, it checks if the collection _contains_ a given element, so when you pass `suspects.contains(_)` you are checking if the **Option** contains a **function** which will never be true. What you want is `exists` which checks if the collection contains at least one element that satisfies the given predicate.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer on your question: it happens because you are using `Option` `contains` method wrong when trying to compare **function** (`String => Boolean`) with **option value** which is `String`.

But there are some difficulties with `contains` method in `Option`.
Let's take a look at `contains` definition in scala source code:

```
/**@example {{{
 *  // Returns true because Some instance contains string "something" which equals "something".
 *  Some("something") contains "something"
 *
 *  // Returns false because "something" != "anything".
 *  Some("something") contains "anything"
 *
 *  // Returns false when method called on None.
 *  None contains "anything"
 *  }}}
 *
 *  @param elem the element to test.
 *  @return `true` if the option has an element that is equal (as
 *  determined by `==`) to `elem`, `false` otherwise.
 */
final def contains[A1 >: A](elem: A1): Boolean =
  !isEmpty && this.get == elem
```

We see that `contains` compares containing value of `Option[A]` with some passed element with type `A1` that has `A` as a lower type bound `[A1 >: A]`. It means the type parameter `A1` or the abstract type `A1` refer to a supertype of type `A`. It means we can pass any supertype of `String` type to check `contains` for example `Any`.
In your case you are trying to pass into contains **function** `String => Boolean` but take a look at `Function1` definition:

```
trait Function1[@specialized(scala.Int, scala.Long, scala.Float, scala.Double) -T1, @specialized(scala.Unit, scala.Boolean, scala.Int, scala.Float, scala.Long, scala.Double) +R] extends AnyRef
```

it is a trait which extends `AnyRef` (and `Any` also). So for compiler it's a legal case, it checks what `String` is a subtype of `Any` and compiles code. In runtime it tries to compare `String` value and **function** `String => Boolean` (`String` != `String => Boolean`) and this is the reason that `contains` returns you always `false` and filter empty list.

So to solve your main problem - filter list correctly using map, it is better to use `exists` function:

```
val people = Seq(Person("Ned", Some("d")), Person("Alex", None))
val suspects = Map("c" -> 1, "d" -> 2)

val resultExist = people.filter { p =>
  p.nickName.exists {
    suspects.contains
  }
}
val resultExistUnsugar = people.filter { p =>
  p.nickName.exists {
    n => suspects.contains(n)
  }
}
println(resultExist) // List(Person(Ned,Some(d)))
println(resultExistUnsugar) // List(Person(Ned,Some(d)))
```

To protect type-safety your code I would recommend you to set concrete type parameter when you are using `contains` method:

```
// it will not compile because suspects.contains type is not String
val result1 = people.filter(_.nickName.contains[String](suspects.contains))
// it will not compile also by the same reason
val result2 = people.filter { p =>
  p.nickName.contains[String] {
    n => suspects.contains(n) 
  }
}
```

But we are still don't know why `contains` has type parameter bounds `[A1 >: A]`. To clarify this let's look at `Option[+A]` class definition:

```
sealed abstract class Option[+A] extends Product with Serializable { // ... }
```

Here we see that `Option` has covariance type parameter `+A` and this is the reason that we should add parameter bounds to `contains` method. See more in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678998/scala-why-does-seq-contains-take-an-any-argument-instead-of-an-argument-of-the) why.

In conclusion:

- Be careful using `contains` method in all containers not only in `Option`
- It's better to bound some methods which can be type parametrized for type-safety and more predictable behavior
- More about lower type bounds and covariance on [docs.scala-lang](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/lower-type-bounds.html)

Comment: I'm kind of amazed that type checks.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt I updated answer and added more expanded explanation of type checks in compile time.