# Why does Seq[V] not extend Map[Int,V] nor does Set[V] extend Map[V,Bool]?

Tags: oop, scala, subclass

The three immediate subtypes of `Iterable` are `Map`, `Seq`, and `Set`.  It seems like—aside from performance issues—a `Seq` is a map from integers to values, and a `Set` is a map from values to booleans (true if the value is in the set, false otherwise).

If this is the case, why is this not expressed in the type system by making `Seq[V]` extend `Map[Int, V]` and `Set[V]` extend `Map[V, Boolean]`?

Comment: `Set` and `Seq` have very different semantics from `Map`, so it wouldn't make sense to expose them that way.

Comment: @Gabe, could you give a specific example of what you mean by "different semantics"?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but Madoc's answer is dispositive.

Comment: Some interesting / relevant discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676615/why-is-scalas-immutable-set-not-covariant-in-its-type

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, they sort of do, at least actually common functionality. `Seq[B]` inherits from `Int => B` (via `PartialFunction[Int, B]`), `Map[A, B]` inherits from `A => B` (also via `PartialFunction[A, B]`), and `Set[A]` inherits from `A => Boolean`.  Thus, as far as function application and composition methods are concerned, all three can be used interchangeably.  Additionally, they can be used interchangeably as far as traversal goes, as all implement `TraversableLike`.

Comment: Thanks!  In that case, I guess my question shifts a bit: what's the fundamental, 30-words-or-less difference between a Map[A,B] and Function[A,B]?

Comment: @Adam A `Map` is traversable, while a `Function` isn't. So a `Map` can enumerate its keys, but a `Function` cannot do the same for its parameters.

Answer (score 8):

Seeing a sequence as an assignment from integers to elements is only one way to describe what a sequence is. There are other ways, and there is no reason why that way of describing a sequence should become canonical. The actual purpose of a sequence is to make a bunch of elements accessible and traversable. A sequence is not required to actually assign integer numbers to the elements. For example, most `Stream` implementations probably don't have a counter running in parallel to the traversal. Requiring that would impose an unnecessary overhead on the implementation.

Besides, a `Map[K,V]` is also an `Iterable[(K,V)]`. Following your suggestion, a `Seq[A]` would also have to be a `Map[Int,A]`, which would by that also make it an `Iterable[(Int,A)]`. Since `Seq` extends `Iterable`, this would make the `Seq[A]` both an `Iterable[A]` and an `Iterable[(Int,A)]` (and, recursively, an `Iterable[(Int,(Int,A))]`, `Iterable[(Int,(Int,(Int,A)))]`, and so on), which is not an allowed way of inheritance in Scala.

You can construct a similar argument for your suggestion regarding `Set`.

Comment: I think the second argument is compelling.  To simplify it, if `Seq[A]` extended `Map[Int,A]`, what would `seq.elements()` return?

Comment: Interesting.  Haskell's type system suffers from no such limitation (in fact, it flaunts this sort of polymorphism left and right).  Interesting to see how Scala's underlying theory has limited its standard library.

Comment: @Adam I don't see Haskell getting out of that one either. If you `foldr` as list in Haskell, you don't fold tuples `(Int, A)`: you fold `A`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if *all* you care about `Seq` and `Set` was that, you'd have a point. Myself, I happen to think that's one of the least importants aspects, and one which is already well represented by all of them being *functions*.

That is, a `Map` is a function of a key into a value, a `Seq` is a function of an `Int` into a value, and a `Set` is a function of a value into a `Boolean`. This property, which you called a "map", is a funciton. And it is already shared by all three.

What, in my opinion, `Map`, `Seq` and `Set` are really about are:

- A `Seq` is concerned about knowing in what order its elements are. Conceptually, how would you prepend an element in a `Map`? You'd have to renumber all keys!
- A `Set` is concerned about the presence or absence of an element. How one would model that in a `Map`? It would have to be a map with default value -- not a common map -- and one in which all non-default values are the same! That is clearly a degenerate behavior, not an abstraction.
- A `Map` is concerned about mapping arbitrary keys to arbitrary values. A `Seq` doesn't have arbitrary keys, and a `Set` doesn't have arbitrary values.

Comment: "Well, if all you care about" -- well, my question could be rephrased as "what, specifically, is it that the Scala library designers care about which led them to make this decision"?

Comment: @Adam See http://www.scala-lang.org/sid/3, http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html and http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html.