# missing parameter type error by calling toSet

Tags: scala

Why this code doesn't work:

```
scala> List('a', 'b', 'c').toSet.subsets.foreach(e => println(e))

<console>:8: error: missing parameter type
              List('a', 'b', 'c').toSet.subsets.foreach(e => println(e))
                                                        ^
```

But when I split it then it works fine:

```
scala> val itr=List('a', 'b', 'c').toSet.subsets
itr: Iterator[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Char]] = non-empty iterator

scala> itr.foreach(e => println(e))
Set()
Set(a)
Set(b)
Set(c)
Set(a, b)
Set(a, c)
Set(b, c)
Set(a, b, c)
```

And this code is OK as well:

```
Set('a', 'b', 'c').subsets.foreach(e => println(e))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type inference on Set failing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544536/type-inference-on-set-failing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, there's a simpler version of the code that has the same issue:

```
List('a', 'b', 'c').toSet.foreach(e => println(e))
```

This doesn't work either

```
List('a', 'b', 'c').toBuffer.foreach(e => println(e))
```

However, these work just fine:

```
List('a', 'b', 'c').toList.foreach(e => println(e))
List('a', 'b', 'c').toSeq.foreach(e => println(e))
List('a', 'b', 'c').toArray.foreach(e => println(e))
```

If you go take a look at the [`List` class documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) you'll see that the methods that work return some type parameterized with `A`, whereas methods that don't work return types parameterized with `B >: A`. The problem is that the Scala compiler can't figure out which `B` to use! That means it will work if you tell it the type:

```
List('a', 'b', 'c').toSet[Char].foreach(e => println(e))
```

Now as for *why* `toSet` and `toBuffer` have that signature, I have no idea...

Lastly, not sure if this is helpful, but this works too:

```
// I think this works because println can take type Any
List('a', 'b', 'c').toSet.foreach(println)
```

**Update:** After poking around the docs a little bit more I noticed that the method works on all the types with a *covariant* type parameter, but the ones with an *invariant* type parameter have the `B >: A` in the return type. Interestingly, although `Array` is invariant in Scala they provide two version of the method (one with `A` and one with `B >: A`), which is why it doesn't have that error.

I also never really answered why breaking the expression into two lines works. When you simply call `toSet` on its own, the compiler will automatically infer `A` as `B` in the type for the resulting `Set[B]`, unless you do give it a specific type to pick. This is just how the type inference algorithm works. However, when you throw *another* unknown type into the mix (i.e. the type of `e` in your lambda) then the inference algorithm chokes and dies—it just can't handle an unknown `B >: A` and an unknown type of `e` as well.