# Scala's type inference with Sets behaves... strangely?

Tags: scala, type-inference, scala-collections

Strange as it may seem, this does not work:

```
scala> (1 to 6).toSet map (_ / 2)
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$div(2))
              (1 to 6).toSet map (_ / 2)
                                  ^
```

However, using `to[Set]` instead of `toSet` does:

```
scala> (1 to 6).to[Set] map (_ / 2)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(2, 0, 3, 1)
```

Huh. o_O

Also consider that this works:

```
scala> val s = (1 to 6).toSet; s map (_ / 2)
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(2, 0, 3, 1)
```

As `Range.Inclusive` is a first-order type, as suggested by @AlexIv, keep in mind that this also won't work with `List[Int]`:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).toSet map (_ / 2)
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$
div(2))
              List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).toSet map (_ / 2)
                                                ^
```

And as previously, this works:

```
scala> val s = List[Int](1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).toSet; s map (_ / 2)
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(2, 0, 3, 1)
```

---

**Edit**: duplicate of [Type inference fails on Set made with .toSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544536/type-inference-on-set-failing)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/onen9RsUkH4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typer phase (`scala -Xprint:typer`) hides the answer:

```
private[this] val res7: <error> = Predef.intWrapper(1).to(6).toSet[B].map[B, That]({
  ((x: Nothing) => Predef.identity[Nothing](x))
})();
```

`(1 to 6)` returns a Range.Inclusive, which is a first-order type and not a type constructor, it's not parameterized, but `Set[A]` expects/requires you to provide it some type and returns you a type. When you call `toSet`, scalac expects some type, cause `Inclusive` doesn't have `toSet` method, it's inherited from `TraversableOnce` and is a generic method, so you need explicitly provide some type:

```
(1 to 6).toSet[Int].map(identity)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4)
```

`toBuffer` also doesn't work, other conversions works perfectly and this two methods have a similar implementation:

```
def toBuffer[B >: A]: mutable.Buffer[B] = to[ArrayBuffer].asInstanceOf[mutable.Buffer[B]]

def toSet[B >: A]: immutable.Set[B] = to[immutable.Set].asInstanceOf[immutable.Set[B]]
```

Comment: Okay. But this also won't work with a `List[Int]` which is a type constructor. (Updating the question.)

Comment: @MichałRus i've added some info. Methods `toSet` and `toBuffer` expects a type argument which has `A` as it's lower bound. So it is inferred as `toSet[B >: Int]`.