# Problem with bounded type parameterised case class and default args in Scala

Tags: scala, case-class, default-arguments

Consider the following (tested with Scala 2.8.1 and 2.9.0):

```
trait Animal
class Dog extends Animal

case class AnimalsList[A <: Animal](list:List[A] = List())
case class AnimalsMap[A <: Animal](map:Map[String,A] = Map())

val dogList = AnimalsList[Dog]()  // Compiles
val dogMap = AnimalsMap[Dog]()    // Does not compile
```

The last line fails with:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[Nothing,Nothing]
 required: Map[String,Main.Dog]
Note: Nothing <: String, but trait Map is invariant in type A.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: String`. (SLS 3.2.10)
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
    val dogMap = AnimalsMap[Dog]()    // Does not compile
                       ^
one error found
```

Changing it to `val dogMap = AnimalsMap[Dog](Map())` fixes it, but no longer takes advantage of the default argument value.

Why is the default value being inferred as Map[Nothing,Nothing], given that List counterpart works as expected? Is there a way to create an AnimalsMap instance that uses the default value for the `map` arg?

---

**Edit:** I've accepted an answer to my more-pressing second question, but I'd still be interested to know why the key type to `Map()` is inferred differently between these two cases:

```
case class AnimalsMap1(map:Map[String,Animal] = Map())
val dogs1 = AnimalsMap1() // Compiles

case class AnimalsMap2[A <: Animal](map:Map[String,A] = Map())
val dogs2 = AnimalsMap2[Dog]() // Does not compile
```

---

**Edit 2:** Seems that type bounds are irrelevant - any parametric type to the case class causes the problem:

```
case class Map3[A](map:Map[String,A] = Map())
val dogs3 = Map3[Dog]() // Does not compile
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just give the compiler a little help:

```
case class AnimalsMap[A <: Animal](map:Map[String,A] = Map[String, A]())
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'll leave the details of why your solution doesn't work to someone better acquainted with Scala's type inference…

**Edit:** See [IttayD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135663/problem-with-bounded-type-parameterised-case-class-and-default-args-in-scala/6136531#6136531) for a nice explanation of this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, this was the compiler hint I was looking for to avoid type annotations at the call-site.

Comment: Or Map.empty[String, A] to avoid creating a new empty map.

Answer (score 21):

Scala has a feature where you can define a class to be covariant / contravariant in its generic parameters.

As an example to covariance: it is natural to think that if `class Student extends Person` then `List[Student]` "extends" `List[Person]`. This is because every method that accepts a `List[Person]` should have no problem working with an object `List[Student]`. This is not possible in Java (without making the method also generic).

Contravariance is the opposite and is a bit trickier to explain. It is required when the type is supposed to be pushed to the generic class, not read (in `List[Person]` you read the elements of the list). The general example is a function. The types of the arguments to a function are put into it, so if a method expects a function `Person => String` it can't be called with a function `Student => String` (it will call the argument with a person, but it expects a student)

Scala also defines `Nothing` to implicitly extend everything. It is the bottom type. So `List[Nothing]` always "extends" `List[X]` for any X. `List()` creates `List[Nothing]` and the covariance is why you can write `val x: List[Person] = List()`.

Anyways, Map is invariant in its key types. The reason is that a `Map[A, B]` is like a function `A => B` so it can only be contravariant in `A`. Another way is to think what happens if you pass a `Map[Student, String]` to a method expecting `Map[Person, String]`, obviously it may try to put `Person` objects in there which is not good, the other way is OK. On the other hand, a Map can be viewed as `Iterable[(A, B)]`, here it should be covariant in A. So it is invariant in its value.

The result is you cannot assign a `Map[Nothing, Nothing]` to a variable of type `Map[String, Animal]`. `Map()` creates a `Map[Nothing, Nothing]`

The compiler tells you this:

```
scala> val dogs3 = Map3[Dog]()
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[Nothing,Nothing]
 required: Map[String,Dog]
Note: Nothing <: String, but trait Map is invariant in type A.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: String`. (SLS 3.2.10)
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
       val dogs3 = Map3[Dog]()
                       ^
```

Comment: Ah, right, good point about `List()` returning a `List[Nothing]`. @Kristian, you'd then have the same problem with a `Set`, as sets are (unfortunately…) [invariant in their element type (yes, immutable sets, too)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676615/why-is-scalas-immutable-set-not-covariant-in-its-type).

Comment: Um, actually Map is invariant in its _key_ type, not its _value_ type (which is covariant). But yes, the fact that the compiler infers the key type to be Nothing seems to be causing the issue. I guess it is a limitation of the inferencer used in the compiler that it can't be inferred as a String. I've accepted @Jean-Philippe's answer because it answers the second part of the question, which is more important to me at the moment :-)