# "generics" in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics

In Java I would write

```
void foo(final Set<? extends SomeClass> someObjects) { /* ... */ }
```

What do I write in Scala?

```
def foo(someObjects : Set[AnyRef[SomeClass])
```

But this doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

I rarely find myself writing code like this any more. The reason is that, in your example

```
void foo(final Set<? extends SomeClass> someObjects) { /* ... */ }
//                ^^^^^^^^^^
//                use-site variance annotation
```

The *variance annotation* denotes you can only access the collection, not update it. It's highly probable that you could re-write the method as follows

```
void foo(final Collection<? extends SomeClass> someObjects) { /* ... */ }
```

That is, if you can only access elements in the set, it's unlikely that you *need* it to be a `Set`. In scala, this means using `Iterable` or `Traversable` - but these types *in Scala* are **covariant** in their type parameter (they are declared `Iterable[+A]` - the `+` is a *declaration-site variance annotation*). Hence there is no need for a use-site variance annotation:

```
def foo(itr: Iterable[SomeClass])
```

Then you can pass a `Set[SomeClassImpl]` freely into this method:

```
scala> trait T; class S extends T
defined trait T
defined class S

scala> def foo(itr: Iterable[T]) = println(itr.isEmpty)
foo: (itr: Iterable[T])Unit

scala> Set(new S)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[S] = Set(S@e1ed5b)

scala> foo(res1)
false
```

The reason that scala's `Set[A]` is not covariant in `A` is that it implements `A => Boolean` (i.e. *Function1*), which is *contravariant* in its input. Hence `Set[A]` must be invariant in `A`. Some chump has [asked this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676615/why-is-scalas-immutable-set-not-covariant-in-its-type).

In fact, it's much more common that I now use `Set` as an *implementation detail* of a predicate function. So, for example:

```
def bar(p: SomeClass => Boolean)
```

In this event; you could use:

```
scala> bar(res1.toSet[T])
```

Answer (score 5):

The literal translation for

```
void foo(final Set<? extends SomeClass> someObjects) { /* ... */ }
```

is

```
def foo(someObjects: Set[_ <: SomeClass]) { /* ... */ }
```

or

```
def foo(someObjects: Set[_ <: SomeClass]): Unit = { /* ... */ }
```

If you are overriding some method in a Java class, prepend `override` to `def`. If you are not, please consider doing things in a different manner, as explained by the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the dependency by using a type bound:

```
def foo[A <: SomeClass]( someObjects: Set[A] ): Unit = ...
```

Here `A <: SomeClass` means that `A` extends `SomeClass`, and you can use `B >: SomeClass` to express than `B` should be a super class of `SomeClass`.