# Scala: Have immutable Set and immutable Map key become Covariant?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I've read here [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676615/why-is-scalas-immutable-set-not-covariant-in-its-type) and other places that Scala's immutable Set and the the Key in immutable Map are invariant.

However the following compiles and runs fine in 2.10.0M5

```
type MapCanvT <: Component with VistaIn
def newMapCanv: MapCanvT
val canv1 = newMapCanv
var vistas = Set[VistaIn](canv1)// Map[VistaIn, Option[CSplit]]((canv1, None))
```

The Map version that is commented out also compiles and runs fine. This would be a very useful and significant change, that I haven't noticed any documentation for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Covariance means that you can do this:

```
var vistas: Set[VistaIn] = Set[MapCanvT](canv1)
```

(which you can’t)

```
var vistas = Set[VistaIn](canv1)
```

is inferred to

```
var vistas = Set[VistaIn](canv1: VistaIn)
```

and thus `canv1` fits in nicely because `VistaIn` is a supertype of `MapCanvT`.

---

To answer your question: The Scala 2.10.0 milestone releases [still have an invariant Set](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/milestone/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Set). (Attention: No stable link.)

Comment: I see, now you explain it, that makes a lot more sense. I'd avoided Sets because of that misunderstanding. Although I would still imagine its an irritating limitation.