# Returning immutable.Map with covariant type

Tags: scala, collections, types, covariance

I have a Container type that is covariant on its type parameter.

```
  class Container[+T](val map: Map[Int, T] = Map.empty[Int, T]){
    def add[B >: T](i: Int, b: B) = new Container(map + (i->b))
//    lazy val freqs = (map.toList groupBy (x=>x._2) mapValues(_.size))
//    lazy val uniq = map.toSet
      lazy val keySet = map.keySet
  }
```

I was thinking that the reason I get errors trying to compile with freqs or uniq uncommented has to do with what Mr. Spiewak wrote in his answer here, that `Set`s and `Map`s are invariant in the relevant parameter.

[Why is Scala's immutable Set not covariant in its type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676615/why-is-scalas-immutable-set-not-covariant-in-its-type)

However I was a bit surprised to find that it was no problem to include keySet which does return a `Set` whose type is T.

I was able to work around this partially by writing

```
lazy val freqs:Map[_ <: Any, Int] = 
  (map.toList groupBy (x=>x._2) mapValues(_.size))
```

But this is less than ideal because the key type comes out as Any. I'd like to be able to also say

```
lazy val uniqueValues = freqs.keySet
```

And get a `Set[T]` instead of a `Set[Any]`

- How can I best implement `freqs` as above?
- How does `keySet` return a Set[T] when other methods fail?
- How can I get a `Set[T]` of unique values in the Map?
- Why does _ <: Any allow this to compile?

Thanks!

Comment: Right off it seems the `Map` is backward. Do know the frequencies are all distinct?

Comment: There are two maps mentioned, and neither is backward. The first Map is the Container parameter, a Map[Int, T]: each Int is an alias for a T. The second map is the return type of freqs, Map[T, Int] which is a count of the number of aliases for each T.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However I was a bit surprised to find that it was no problem to include keySet which does return a Set whose type is T

No it does not. `map` is of type `Map[Int, T]`, so while its **values** are of type `T`, its **keys** are of type `Int`. So `keySet` here is of type `Set[Int]` (and **not** `Set[T]`) which means that there is no problem with `T`'s covariance.

> How does keySet return a Set[T] when other methods fail?

It does not (see above)

> How can I get a Set[T] of unique values in the Map?

Given that `Set` is invariant in its type parameter, there is simply no way to have any val of type `Set[T]` inside `Container`, unless you mark these vals as `private[this]`, or make `Container` invariant in `T`.

> How can I best implement freqs as above?

Same problem as above.

> Why does _ <: Any allow this to compile?

Because when explicitly stating that `freq`is of type `Map[_ <: Any, Int]` you removed any dependence to `T`, thus there is no problem as far as variance is concerned. If you don't explictly state the type of `freq`, scala (correctly) infers the type as `Map[T, Int]`, which **does** depend on `T` in an invariant position.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but adding private[this] doesn't seem to have helped.

    `class Container[+T](val map: Map[Int, T] = Map.empty[Int, T]){
      def add[B >: T](i: Int, b: B) = new Container(map + (i->b));
      private[this] lazy val freqs = (map.toList groupBy (x=>x._2) mapValues(_.size))

    }`

Comment: Which version of scala are you using, and can you try with a more recent one?

Comment: I checked it, and indeed it does work in scala 2.10, but not in scala 2.9. Apparently in scala 2.9 having a `private[this]` val of type `T` works, but if you change the type to a class that is invariant in `T` (as opposed to simply **being** `T`) such as `Set[T]`, it does not work anymore. This looks like a scala 2.9 bug to me.