# implicit conversion from scala Set to Java Set

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have the following:

```
    class Goo
    trait Bar[D] {
     def toD : D
    }
    class Moo extends Bar[Goo] {
      def toD : Goo = new Goo
    }

    object Foo {
      import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
      import java.util

      implicit def scalaSetToJavaSet[D](bars: Set[Bar[D]]) : util.Set[D] = bars.map(_.toD)
    }  

    trait Zoo {
      import java.util
      import Foo._

      var javaSet : util.Set[Goo] = Set(new Moo) //compile error

      var explicitJavaSet: util.Set[Goo] = scalaSetToJavaSet(Set(new Moo)) //works!!!
    }
```

When I try to compile this code I get an error:

```
"error: type mismatch;
   found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Moo]
   required: java.util.Set[Goo]
           var javaSet : util.Set[Goo] = ***Set(new Moo)***"
```

The explicit definition compiles. Why doesn't the implicit conversion work?

Comment: Just a small addition: I prefer to import JavaConverters and make conversions explicit with `asJava`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed tricky. Basically your idea is correct. You define a conversion method `scalaSetToJavaSet` that is imported. The problem comes from the fact that (Scala's) `Set[A]` is invariant in its type parameter `A`. That means that `Set[Moo]` is not a sub-type of `Set[Bar[_]]`.

In order to fix that, you need to tell the implicit conversion that the set element can be a sub-type of bar:

```
implicit def scalaSetToJavaSet[D, B <: Bar[D]](bars: Set[B]): java.util.Set[D] = 
  bars.map(_.toD)

val javaSet: java.util.Set[Goo] = scala.Set(new Moo)  // ok
```

---

You can read this now as: Given a type `D` and some sub-type of `Bar` whose type parameter is `D`, conduct the conversion. This method is now called as `scalaSetToJavaSet[Goo, Moo]` (and not `scalaSetToJavaSet[Goo, Bar[Goo]]`).

---

As the others have pointed out, it is easier to use a ready-made conversion from `JavaConversions` instead of writing your own.

Comment: Why did they make Seq different than Set?

Comment: [Popular question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676615/why-is-scalas-immutable-set-not-covariant-in-its-type)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly implicit function `scalaSetToJavaSet` does not work because it expects `Set[Bar[D]]` and you are passing `Set[Moo]`. This is because type parameter of [Set](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.Set) is invariant and not co-variant (It would had worked in case of List).

So a short answer is

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
var javaSet : util.Set[Moo] = Set(new Moo)
```

Or you can change your declaration to:

```
implicit def scalaSetToJavaSet[D,T <:Bar[D]](bars: Set[T]) : util.Set[D] = bars.map(_.toD)

var javaSet : util.Set[Goo] = Set(new Moo)
```

Now it says that you can pass any type which extends `Bar[D]` and hence works with Moo