# Scala covariance errors

Tags: scala, covariance

I'm trying to compile the following code, but the last line does not compile:

```
class SuperContainer (
  val shapeSets: Set[MyContainer[Shape]] = Set.empty[MyContainer[Shape]]) {

  def addAct(el: MyContainer[Shape]) = {
    new SuperContainer(shapeSets + el)
  }

}

class MyContainer[A](val ls: Set[A] = Set.empty[A]) {
  def addElement(el: A) = {
    new MyContainer(ls + el)
  }
}  


abstract class Shape

case class Circle(radius: Int) extends Shape {
  override def toString = "Circle(" + radius + ")"
}
case class Square(s: Int) extends Shape {
  override def toString = "Square(" + s + ")"
}


object MyContainer {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //Circle Container
    val myc1 = new MyContainer[Circle]()
    val myc11 = myc1.addElement(new Circle(6))

    //Square Container
    val myc2 = new MyContainer[Square]()
    val myc21 = myc2.addElement(new Square(6))


    val scont = new SuperContainer
    scont.addAct(myc11) //does not compile
  }
}
```

Scala compiler suggests me to use +A in MyContainer class definition, but by doing that, other compile errors occur. Am I doing something wrong or this is just a Scala limitation? Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve: your add* functions don't return anything (you're missing the equals sign) and don't store the modified data anywhere either.

Comment: You're right. It was just some typo. I corrected the code. I also now store the modified data.

Comment: The compiler is right, your SuperContainer is invariant, and it should be covariant. What are the other errors that show up when you make the correction?

Comment: When i use `class MyContainer[+A](val ls: Set[A] = Set.empty[A])` I get 2 errors. In the class definition: _covariant type A occurs in invariant position in type => Set[A] of value ls_ and in method `addElement(el: A)`: _covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type A of value el_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want, `MyContainer` has to be covariant:

```
class MyContainer[+A](val ls: Set[A] = Set.empty[A]) // ...
```

Now, your definition of `addElement` will cause an error, since `A` appears in contravariant position (as a function argument in this case). You will have to adapt your signature as follows:

```
def addElement[B >: A](el: B): MyContainer[B]
```

This makes sense if you think of it: If you have a `Container[Circle]` (which can be seen as a `Container[Shape]` due to covariance) and you add a `Shape`, you have a `Container[Shape]` at the end and not a `Container[Circle]`.

The implementation of `addElement` will not change.

Further, you cannot make `Set[A]` available outside the class (i.e. you have to remove the `val`), since `Set[A]` [is not covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676615/why-is-scalas-immutable-set-not-covariant-in-its-type). If you want to access elements, you'll have to add additional methods to query the set.

```
class MyContainer[+A](ls: Set[A] = Set.empty[A]) // ...
```

**UPDATE**

This is to explain clearer, why `Set[A]` cannot be part of `MyContainer[+A]`'s public API. Say we have:

```
class A
class B extends A
```

Imagine the following:

```
val x: MyContainer[A] = new MyContainer[B]
```

We can do that due to the covariance. However, if we could call now:

```
val s = x.ls // get internal set
```

We expect `s` to be of type `Set[A]`. However, the internal `Set` of `x` is a `Set[B]` [which is **not** a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676615/why-is-scalas-immutable-set-not-covariant-in-its-type) `Set[A]`. Therefore this is not correctly typed.

Comment: I understood the most part of your answer, apart from the last sentence. Do you mean that I should remove the Set[A] from the constructor? By doing what you suggested, now `addElement` seems to compile, but i get an error about the Set[A]: _covariant type A occurs in invariant position in type => Set[A] of value ls_

Comment: @kwstas Have a look at the updated answer. You cannot expose the `Set` in `MyContainer`'s public API, since it is invariant.

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked fine, even though I can't really understand why (I'm little bit confused with covariance etc). Why we cannot expose the Set to the public API? Is it because we don't know it's type?

Comment: Thanks again for your explanation. So the problem is that a set is invariant, but if I change the set with a list, I can expose it in the API, because Lists are covariant. I think I got it know :)