# Why is Seq.containsSlice not type-safe?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

While debugging my program, I found that I had made the mistake of supplying the wrong argument to the `containsSlice` method of a `Seq[Char]`.  I had supplied a `Seq[Boolean]` which is of course never contained in the `Seq[Char]`.

Why did the compiler let me do this?  Can't this method be implemented in a type-safe way in the Scala collections library?  I think it must have been done deliberately to be able to supply a `Seq[Any]`, which could theoretically be all `Char`s.  But shouldn't the designers have kept this method type-safe and add some non-type-safe method like `containsAnySlice`?

**EDIT**:
I've tried creating my own type-safe `containsSlice` method outside of the collection class hierarchy, but for some reason the code in the `test` method compiles while I had hoped it wouldn't:

```
object Seqs {
  def containsSlice[A, B <: A](s1: Seq[A], s2: Seq[B]): Boolean = {
    s1.containsSlice(s2)
  }
  def test = {
    val sc: Seq[Char] = Seq('A','B','C')
    val sb: Seq[Boolean] = Seq(true, false)
    containsSlice(sc, sb)
  }
}
```

I guess this is because the common supertype of `Char` and `Boolean` (`AnyVal`) is inferred for type parameter `A`, and I need to explicitly call `containsSlice[Char](sc, sb)` if I don't want that (but then I could just use `sc.containsSlice[Char](sb)`).

To make it not compile for incompatible `Seq`s, the only way I could do this is use 2 parameter lists so the correct type gets inferred:

```
object Seqs {
  def containsSlice[A, B <: A](s1: Seq[A])(s2: Seq[B]): Boolean = {
    s1.containsSlice(s2)
  }
  def test = {
    val sc: Seq[Char] = Seq('A','B','C')
    val sb: Seq[Boolean] = Seq(true, false)
    containsSlice(sc)(sb) // does not compile, yay!
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution means you can't ask if oranges containsSlice fruits, even if all the fruits are oranges in the sequence.  Usually you want to balk if the common type is `Any`. See my answer, which includes the improved signature at the end.

Comment: @som-snytt I was willing to sacrifice that flexibility because it's the less common case.  After all, you can't ask if a certain fruit is contained in a Set[Orange] either (without casting to Orange).

Comment: `Set` is different because it is invariant in the type param. Sample Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/a/678637/1296806  If a basket of oranges is a basket of fruit, it's natural to ask if this basket of fruit was selected from that basket of oranges. Happy Thanksgiving.  I should have used a turkey metaphor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Seq is declared to be covaraint in its type parameter: `trait Seq[+A]`  this means that `Seq[A]` is a subclass of `Seq[B]` if `A` is a subclass of `B`.  The parameter to `containsSlice` is naturally in a contra-variant position, which means that it CANNOT match the type parameter A, since A is already declared as covariant.  Try writing this yourself:

```
trait MySeq[+A] {
  def containsSlice(as: Seq[A]): Boolean
}
```

The compiler will complain:

```
error: covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type Seq[A] of value as
  def containsSlice(as: Seq[A]): Boolean
                    ^
one error found
```

And you can if you play around with this, how you cannot guarantee type safety anyway.  Lets pretend that the compiler allowed this definition.  In your example you had a `Seq[Char]`.  Well because of the covariance of Seq, this should be allowed:

```
val myseq: Seq[Char] = List('a','b','c')
val anyseq: Seq[Any] = myseq
```

We are allowed to do this because `Seq[Char]` is a subtype of `Seq[Any]` since `Char` is a subtype of `Any`.  Now, what is the type of `containsSlice` on anyseq?  its `Seq[Any]` since the type parameter of `Seq` in our `anyseq` is `Any`, and thus your type safety is gone.

Comment: I'm a Scala newbie coming from Java so although I understand what covariance means, I'm unsure what a "contra-variant position" is.  But am I right in saying that making `Seq` covariant in its type parameter increases flexibility at the cost of some type-safety?  Apparently for `Set` the decision was made to make it invariant (with e.g. a type-safe contains method).

Answer (score 3):

`containsSlice` is just a call to `indexOfSlice`, which has the following signature:

```
indexOfSlice[B >: A](that: GenSeq[B]): Int
```

`containsSlice` could do the same thing.

It's useful to constrain the type param with a lower bound so you can do this:

```
apm@mara:~/tmp$ scalam -Ywarn-infer-any 
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-M7 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> "abcdef" contains 8
<console>:8: warning: a type was inferred to be `AnyVal`; this may indicate a programming error.
              "abcdef" contains 8
                                ^
res0: Boolean = false
```

The warning tells you that type safety has been compromised.

`-Xlint` includes `-Ywarn-infer-any`.

But check this out:

```
scala> "abcdef" indexOfSlice (1 to 10)
res1: Int = -1
```

No warning?

You can turn on the fancy new `-Ytyper-debug` to see:

```
|    |    |    |    |    \-> [B >: Char](that: scala.collection.GenSeq[B], from: Int)Int <and> [B >: Char](that: scala.collection.GenSeq[B])Int
|    |    |    |    solving for (B: ?B)
```

and

```
|    |    |    |    solving for (B: ?B)
|    |    |    |    \-> Int
```

which seems to mean that in the presence of overloading, you don't get the warning.

That's because of how typechecking is done for overloading.

`-Xprint:typer` confirms that, of course, you wind up with `AnyVal`, but it must happen later:

```
private[this] val res0: Int = scala.this.Predef.augmentString("abcdef").indexOfSlice[AnyVal](scala.this.Predef.intWrapper(1).to(10));
```

We didn't really need another reason that overloading is evil, but did you know that `println` is also evil?

```
scala> println("abcdef" contains 8)
false
```

No warning.

It turns out that the warning is very conservative:

```
  // Can warn about inferring Any/AnyVal as long as they don't appear
  // explicitly anywhere amongst the formal, argument, result, or expected type.
```

Since `println` takes `Any`, that is our expected type for the expression, and we lose the warning.

In summary,

```
import reflect.runtime._
import universe._

case class Foo[+A](a: A) {
  def f[B >: A : TypeTag](other: Foo[B]): String = typeTag[B].toString
  def g[B] = "huh"
  def j[B >: A : TypeTag](other: Foo[B]): String = typeTag[B].toString
  def j[B >: A : TypeTag](other: Foo[B], dummy: Int): String = typeTag[B].toString
}

object Test extends App {
  val x = Foo("abc") f Foo(3)       // warn
  val y = Foo("abc").g
  val w = Foo("abc") j Foo(3)       // nowarn
  val z = Foo("abc") j (Foo(3), 0)
  Console println s"$x $y $w $z"
  val b = "abcdef" contains 8       // warn
  println("abcdef" contains 8)      // nowarn

  implicit class Sectional[+A](val as: Seq[A]) {
    def containsSection[B >: A](other: Seq[B]): Boolean = as containsSlice other
  }
  ("abcdefg": Seq[Char]) containsSection (1 to 10)  // warn
  implicit class Sectional2(val as: String) {
    def containsSection[B >: String](other: Seq[B]): Boolean = as containsSlice other
  }
  "abcdefg" containsSection (1 to 10)  // warn
}
```

Too bad about special-casing String.