# val a: Set[Fruit]=Set[Apple]() does not compile, why? How can it be fixed?

Tags: scala, generics

The line `val a: Set[Fruit]=Set[Apple]` does not compile, why ?

How can this be fixed ?

```
package sandbox.stackOverFlow

class Fruit 
class Apple extends Fruit
class Banana extends Fruit

class Why{
  val a:Set[Fruit]=Set[Apple]() // Does not compile, why ?
  val b:List[Fruit]=List[Apple]() // Does compile.
}
```

Produces compile error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[sandbox.stackOverFlow.Apple]
 required: Set[sandbox.stackOverFlow.Fruit]
Note: sandbox.stackOverFlow.Apple <: sandbox.stackOverFlow.Fruit, but trait Set is invariant in type A.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: sandbox.stackOverFlow.Fruit`. (SLS 3.2.10)
  val a:Set[Fruit]=Set[Apple]()
                         ^
```

EDIT:

As pointed out in Jatin's answer, this question is answered already here : [Why is Scala's immutable Set not covariant in its type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676615/why-is-scalas-immutable-set-not-covariant-in-its-type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type parameter of `Set` (even immutable) is invariant (mainly because `Set[A]` inherits from `A => Boolean`, which is contra variant in `A`). The type parameter of `List` is covariant.

As for how this can be fixed, the compiler gives you a potential solution: using a wildcard, such as

```
val a: Set[_ <: Fruit] = Set[Apple]()
```

Comment: As for how this can be fixed, the compiler gives you a potential solution: using a wildcard, such as `val a: Set[_<:Fruit]=Set[Apple]()`

Comment: Regis could you please put this as an answer, it addresses the issue of fixing it using existential types.

Comment: I have just edited Jean-Philippe Pellet's answer to include this "fix", I hope he won't mind

Answer (score 2):

Because type parameter of [List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) (declared as `List[+A]`)is co-variant where as for [Set](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Set) (declared as `Set[A]`) it is invariant.

In short,

*Co-variance* is: converting broader type to narrow type (say converting `List[Animal` to `List[Dog]`. 
*Contra-variance* is converting narrow type to broader type. For example `Function1[Dog, something]` extends `Function1[Animal, Something]`. Here you are converting `Dog` (narrow) to `Animal` (broader)

*Invariance* does not give you permission to do nay of above.

There are several links available which explain co-variance and contra-variance:

1. [Why is Scala's immutable Set not covariant in its type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676615/why-is-scalas-immutable-set-not-covariant-in-its-type) (@serejja mentioned this is comments)
2. [Why doesn't the example compile, aka how does (co-, contra-, and in-) variance work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/scala-covariance-contravariance-question)
3. http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/01/covariance-and-contravariance-in-scala/
4. http://jatinpuri.com/2012/11/co-variance-contra-variance/

Comment: Yes, but why does that make sense?

Comment: @jhegedus please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676615/why-is-scalas-immutable-set-not-covariant-in-its-type

Answer (score 1):

That's because `List`s are covariant, ant `Set`s are invariant. Look at the definition:

```
sealed abstract class List[+A] extends...

trait Set[A] extends ...
```