# Implicit definition working for Seq but not for Set

Tags: scala, set, implicit, seq

So I've made some utility classes and implicit conversions for them. However, it works fine when converting from a Seq but not from a Set, although the code is the same, and those two traits seem rather similar at first sight. What could be the problem, and how would I fix it?

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

trait Indexed[T] {
  def index: T
}

class IndexMap[T, V <: Indexed[T]] extends HashMap[T, V] {
  override def put(key: T, value: V): Option[V] = {
    require(key == value.index)
    super.put(key, value)
  }
  final def put(value: V): Option[V] = put(value.index, value)
}

trait Named extends Indexed[String] {
  final def index = name
  def name: String
}

type NameMap[T <: Named] = IndexMap[String, Named]
```

This works fine:

```scala
implicit def seq2IndexMap[T, V <: Indexed[T]](s: Seq[V]): IndexMap[T,V] = {
  val ret = new IndexMap[T,V]();
  s.foreach(v => ret.put(v))
  ret
}
```

However, this fails to compile with `type mismatch; found : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Program.ClassData] required: Common.NameMap[Program.ClassData] (which expands to) Common.IndexMap[String,Common.Named]`

```scala
implicit def set2IndexMap[T, V <: Indexed[T]](s: Set[V]): IndexMap[T,V] = {
  val ret = new IndexMap[T,V]();
  s.foreach(v => ret.put(v))
  ret
}
```

On input:

```scala
val c = Class("Test", Set(ClassData("data1", null), ClassData("data2", null)))
```

Where `ClassData` extends `Named`.

I'm using Scala 2.10.

### Edit:

The simplified definitions of Class and ClassData for convenience:

```scala
case class ClassData(name: String, p: Any) extends Named
case class Class(n: String, data: NameMap[ClassData])
```

### Edit 2:

Ok, we found the problem. It was indeed because `Set` is invariant (which I don't understand why).

When I wrote `Set(ClassData("data1", null))`, it made a `Set[ClassData]`, which could not be interpreted as a `Set[Named]`, whereas it worked with `Seq` because `Seq` is covariant.

Interestingly enough, Scala doesn't have any problem when we explicitly call the conversion:

```scala
val c = Class("Test", set2IndexMap((Set(ClassData("data1", null), ClassData("data2", null))))
```

I think Scala is able, in this case, to infer which type of `Set` to infer. In my opinion, this shows how Scala can be too complex. If I also had an error with the explicit version, I could have immediately seen what was wrong with the implicit conversion. I feel like too many things happen behind the scenes, and ultimately you have to know them or you'll get stuck with problems like this.

A solution was to explicitly state the type of the set:

```scala
val c = Class("Test", Set[Named](ClassData("data1", null), ClassData("data2", null)))
```

A better solution was to make the implicit conversion work for `Iterable` or even `Traversable`, which are super traits of both `Seq` and `Set`, and *are* covariant (although `Set` is not, while being covariant *as a* `Iterable`).

```scala
implicit def set2IndexMap[T, V <: Indexed[T]](s: Traversable[V]): IndexMap[T,V] = {
  val ret = new IndexMap[T,V]();
  s.foreach(v => ret.put(v))
  ret
}
```

Comment: Your first code block does not compile. Which `HashMap` was imported but not shown?

Comment: It's scala.collection.mutable.HashMap, since you can see I mutate it.

Comment: By the way, you should avoid core Java library names such as `Class` (defined in java.lang).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infamously, `Set` is invariant in its type parameter.

That seems to make the implicit not apply?

Maybe `V` is not inferred correctly. Sometimes it likes to infer `Nothing`.

(Posting a complete minimization would help someone help you.)

I'll try to decipher the `-Ytyper-debug` when I get a chance, but FTR:

Succeeding on Seq:

```
|    |    |    solving for (A: ?A)
|    |    |    |-- seq2IndexMap BYVALmode-EXPRmode-FUNmode-POLYmode (silent: value b  in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    [adapt] [T, V <: Code.this.Indexed[T]](s: Seq[V])Code.this.IndexM... adapted to [T, V <: Code.this.Indexed[T]](s: Seq[V])Code.this.IndexM...
|    |    |    |    \-> (s: Seq[V])nosetconvert.Test.IndexMap[T,V]
|    |    |    solving for (T: ?T, V: ?V)
|    |    |    [adapt] seq2IndexMap adapted to [T, V <: Code.this.Indexed[T]](s: Seq[V])Code.this.IndexM... based on pt Seq[nosetconvert.Test.ClassData] => nosetconvert.Test.NameMap[nosetconvert.Test.ClassData]
|    |    |    |-- [T, V <: Code.this.Indexed[T]](s: Seq[V])Code.this.IndexM... : pt=nosetconvert.Test.NameMap[nosetconvert.Test.ClassData] BYVALmode-EXPRmode (silent: value b  in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    \-> nosetconvert.Test.IndexMap[String,nosetconvert.Test.Named]
|    |    |    [adapt] [A](elems: A*)CC[A] adapted to [T, V <: Code.this.Indexed[T]](s: Seq[V])Code.this.IndexM... based on pt nosetconvert.Test.NameMap[nosetconvert.Test.ClassData]
|    |    |    \-> nosetconvert.Test.IndexMap[String,nosetconvert.Test.Named]
```

Failing on Set:

```
|    |    |    solving for (A: ?A)
|    |    |    |-- set2IndexMap BYVALmode-EXPRmode-FUNmode-POLYmode (silent: value c  in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    [adapt] [T, V <: Code.this.Indexed[T]](s: Set[V])Code.this.IndexM... adapted to [T, V <: Code.this.Indexed[T]](s: Set[V])Code.this.IndexM...
|    |    |    |    \-> (s: Set[V])nosetconvert.Test.IndexMap[T,V]
|    |    |    |-- nosetconvert.this.Test.set2IndexMap BYVALmode-EXPRmode-FUNmode-POLYmode (silent: value c  in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    [adapt] [T, V <: Code.this.Indexed[T]](s: Set[V])Code.this.IndexM... adapted to [T, V <: Code.this.Indexed[T]](s: Set[V])Code.this.IndexM...
|    |    |    |    \-> (s: Set[V])nosetconvert.Test.IndexMap[T,V]
|    |    |    \-> <error>
```

Comment: What do you mean by complete minimization?

Comment: @LP_ I just meant something that compiles.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was indeed invariance (cf: edited question).