# Scala Set[_] vs Set[Any]

Tags: scala

I have the following line of code:

```
case set: Set[Any] => setFormat[Any].write(set)
```

However, the compiler issues a warning:

> non-variable type argument Any in type pattern
>   scala.collection.Set[Any] is unchecked since it is eliminated by
>   erasure [warn]

Fair enough.

So I change my line to this:

```
case set: Set[_] => setFormat[Any].write(set)
```

Now I get an error:

> [error]  found   : scala.collection.Set[_]
>
> [error]  required:
>   scala.collection.Set[Any]

**Q1. What is the difference between these two?**

Then I change my code to the following:

```
case set: Set[_] => setFormat[Any].write(set.map(s => s))
```

Now it is happy with no errors or warnings.

**Q2. Why does this work??**

Comment: could you give the types/signatures of setFormat and write ?

Comment: just curious, does removing the explicit `[Any]` and the map, as suggested in my answer under "Remark", works in your case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Q1**: A `Set[Any]` is a Set whose elements type is Any. A `Set[_]` is a Set whose elements type is unknown. Maybe it's a `Set[Int]`, maybe a `Set[String]`, maybe a `Set[Any]`. Contrary to most (immutable) collections, Set is not covariant (declaration is `trait Set[A]`, not `trait Set[+A]`). So a `Set[String]` is not a `Set[Any]`, and more generally, you cannot guarantee that a set whose elements type you do not know (i.e. `Set[_]`) is a `Set[Any]`.

**Q2**: It works because whatever the (unknown) type A of the elements of set, the identity function `s => s` can be considered to a a function A => Any. (variance is `Function1[-T1, +R]`. Then, the resulting `set.map(s => s)` can be typed as `Set[Any]`, as required.

**Remark**: Difficult to be sure without the definition of setFormat and write, but do you really need to be explicit with the `[Any]` type argument in `setFormat[Any]`? One may pass an existential to a generic function, i.e

```
val x: X[_] = ....
def f[A](xa: X[A]) = ...
f(x) // allowed
```

but  being explicit at the call site (e.g `f[Any](x)`) will not be allowed, as we do not know whether `X` is an `X[Any]`.

**Note: about Set not being covariant**: This is unfortunate, as one feels very much that a set of Cats is a set of Animals too. Here is one reason for that (there might be others).

Set has a method `def contains(a: A): Boolean` and this signature prevents covariance. Other collections have a `def contains[A1 >: A](a: A): Boolean`, which allows covariance, but which is effectively equivalent to `def contains(a: Any): Boolean`.

It works, because the implementation is based on method `equals`, available everywhere (comes with the JVM) and which takes an argument of type `Any`. It is quite likely that calling with a value of a type unrelated to the list content is a mistake, and that a more constrained signature would be better, but it is a small price to pay for covariance.

But this relaxed signature for `contains` constraints the implementation to be based on `equals` (and possibly `hashCode` too). It would not work for an implementation based on Ordering, which would not accept an untyped argument. Forbidding such (very common) set implementations may be seen as too high a price for covariance.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/676615/86485 ("Why is Scala's immutable Set not covariant in its type?")