# Difference between Future[Any] and Future[_]

Tags: scala, future

Okay, I guess question is already complete in the title.
Nothing big, but I am just wondering. I have a method which returns either a correct value or an error code enum item. For example something like this:

```
def doMyStuff(): Future[_] = {
    val result = db.queryMyData().map {
        case some(data) =>
            val modifiedData = data.doStuff()
            modifiedData
        case None =>
            Errors.THIS_IS_FALSE
    }
    result
}
```

Where `db.queryMyData()` returns a Future, and `data.doStuff()` just modifies the data.

Now I have intuitively written `Future[_]`, cause the return value is flexible. But when looking in other libraries I've seen `Future[Any]` used. Which seems to be logic too, when you use a match-case on the return of the function to check which data it is.

The code which uses that is for example something like this:

```
doMyStuff().map {
    case data: MyDataType => // Blah blah
    case Errors.Value => // error handling
}
```

So, my questions is: What's the difference between the use of **Any** or **_** here, and why should I use the *correct* one?

Comment: I'm thinking of closing this in favor of it being a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186520/scala-any-vs-underscore-in-generics.  I have the golden hammer, so I wanted to get others feedback before marking this as a duplicate and thus closing it.

Comment: I just would like to advice to use `Either[Error, Data]` instead of `Any`

Comment: @Łukasz: Either would be working if it's just two possible return types like in that example. And Either looks less *clean* and readable for me, especially with that `case Left(blah)` stuff in the match. Or what would the real advantage be when using `Either`?

Comment: @cmbaxter That's a very complicated question/answer there and I don't feel like it answers my question. But maybe I just don't understand that stuff there. It doesn't answer what to prefer to use in my case, does it?

Comment: @cmbaxter I wouldn't; that's a more complicated case. There is a much closer case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866944/scala-set-vs-setany, though `Set` isn't covariant.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, am I wrong in thinking that because `Future` is covariant then as Regis Jean-Giles pointed out the use of `_` vs `Any` doesn't matter and only comes down to style?

Comment: @cmbaxter Yes, I think they are pretty much equivalent. There might be some corner cases I am missing.

Comment: I guess when I don't explicitely write the return type of the function, IntelliJ says the function returns `Future[Any]`. Guess that's cause the IDE regocnizes different types inside the future and then says it's Any. So both is valid and it doesn't make a real difference, if I understand correct? But which should I use then?

Comment: Check out this blog post series from S11 - http://typelevel.org/blog/2015/07/13/type-members-parameters.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a matter of semantics:

The *Existential Type*`T[_]` means there is a class/type at the position of `_` for which I do not care at all but it must be there.

`T[Any]` means there has to be a subclass `Any` present.

The difference comes into play when you want to serialize the underlying class.
If you just use `_` without any typebounds you will not be able to use some of the many Scala JSON libraries.

Comment: Thank you, that helps me to understand a bit more. `_` means I don't care and `Any` means I care but it can be everything. So in my example, what would it be? I guess Any would be more correct? (Oh, and a bit offtopic, but your last paragraph, does that mean you can serialize `Any`?)

Comment: Another attempt to state it: `T[Any]` means "at compile time, we know for sure that at runtime, the value might be anything". `T[_]` means "maybe we have some compile-time knowledge here, maybe we don't, it's fine either way".

Comment: Yes. I would go for `Any` when in doubt.

Comment: You definitly can not serialize `_`.