# Bypassing Set's invariance in scala

Tags: scala

As also seen in the scaladoc, [sets are invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676615/why-is-scalas-immutable-set-not-covariant-in-its-type) :( So what do you do when you wish treat one as if it were covariant?

I have a constructor object:

```
object SimpleGraph {
  def apply[ID](vertices: List[AbstractVertex[ID]], edges: Set[AbstractEdge[ID]]) = {
    val simpleGraph = new SimpleGraph[ID, AbstractVertex[ID], AbstractEdge[ID]]
    vertices.map(simpleGraph.addNode)
    edges.map(simpleGraph.addEdge)
    simpleGraph
  }   
}
```

Given the invariance, sets of types that adhere to `T <: AbstractEdge[ID]` won't make it through into my `apply` function. The compilation error suggests using a wildcard type, which as much as I fathom means circumventing type safety altogether (?). My own solution is ugly because it uses cpu cycles and more memory to get over the invariance: changing the prototype's type from `Set` to `List` and converting back and forth between a list and a set to get the data through.

Have you got a better suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: I think we should have a `CovariantSet` type in scala 3.0 that will also need to drop Set's `apply` convenience method, to allow that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not terribly sure about it, because I am currently not able to test it properly, But wouldn't it work to tell your apply the exact type of the items in the set by type parameter?

```
object SimpleGraph {
  def apply[ID, EDGE <: AbstractEdge[ID]](vertices: List[AbstractVertex[ID]], edges: Set[EDGE]) = {
    val simpleGraph = new SimpleGraph[ID, AbstractVertex[ID], AbstractEdge[ID]]
    vertices.foreach(simpleGraph.addNode)
    edges.foreach(simpleGraph.addEdge)
    simpleGraph
  }
}
```

Comment: brilliant! I guess the extra type parameter avoids the variance check on the `edges` parameter, making this work. Great pattern!

Comment: It does at the same time pass the burden to the caller to this apply, as the compiler won't deduce the type parameter but require it stated there. I still wish Scala 3 will rid us of this thorny aspect.