# Scala sealed trait as key on map throws mismatch error

Tags: scala

Would someone help me understand why this does not work?  Scala version 2.10

```
object ColorEnum {
  sealed trait Color
  case object Red extends Color
  case object Blue extends Color
  case object Green extends Color
}
```

Create a Map that accepts a Color as the Key and a String as a value

```
val colorMap = mutable.HashMap[ColorEnum.Color, String]()
```

Put an item on Map using ColorEnum as Key

```
colorMap.put(ColorEnum.Red, "Foo")
```

This throws an exception

```
error: type mismatch
found: ColorEnum.Red.type
required: ColorEnum.Color
```

I must be missing something with my understanding of how this should work.

Thanks

Comment: I already updated my answer by providing link to other related topic with example of how to use case class as a key.

Comment: This compiles for me. Are you sure this the code you're using?

Comment: If I define the trait and the case objects  outside of the `object ColorEnum` hierarchy. Then define a map as `val colorMap = mutable.HashMap[Color, String]()` it works using `colorMap.put(Red, "Foo")`. Creating the sealed trait Color and case objects within ColorEnum  does not work then (at least for me).

Comment: The original code does not work in the shell, but it does in a worksheet.Very frustrating

Answer (score 2):

**Summary:**
As of Scala 2.11 (and all preceding versions of Scala back to 2.8) `Map`'s key is the type `A` in `Map[A, +B]`. And Map doesn't allow covariance when specifying the key; i.e. notice how the A doesn't have a plus (+) sign preceding it.

Here's a specific StackOverflow answer which addresses the details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/678637/501113

**Details:**
Your trait, `Color`, is the type by which you are defining your `Map`. And you define three *descendants* of the `Color` trait. Then, you are attempting to insert these descendants of the `Color` trait (as opposed to an instance of the trait itself) into the `Map`. And the type definition of `Map` only allows direct instances of the `Color` trait, not descendants (defined via `extends` or `with`).

You could use `.asInstanceOf[Color]` when inserting the descendant keys into the `Map` in order to conform to the `Map`'s type requirement for the key. However, be warned using this approach is considered an undesirable code smell.

**Bonus:**
It appears you are attempting to define  your own strongly typed enumeration. Please look at [this answer to a related question regarding defining enumerations in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898932/case-objects-vs-enumerations-in-scala/25923651#25923651).