# Intersect two sets, of a class and of a derived class

Tags: scala, collections, set, covariance

I have two sets, one of them lists instances of a derived class. The set type as created is out of my control, I cannot make sure both are `Set[A]` instead. The `set23` is used in other contexts where I need its type to be `Set[B]`. I would like to intersect:

```
case class A(name: String)
class B(name: String) extends A(name)

val set12 = Set(new A("1"), new A("2"))
val set23 = Set(new B("2"), new B("3"))

set12 intersect set23 // does not work
```

Error is:

> type mismatch;
>   found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[B]
>
> required: scala.collection.GenSet[A]
>
> Note: B <: A, but trait GenSet is invariant in type A.

I am aware `Set` is not covariant, is there some clean workaround without rebuilding the sets? Following works, but I would prefer not to use `asInstanceOf`:

```
set12 intersect set23.asInstanceOf[Set[A]]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the set as `Set(new A("1"), new A("2"))`, it assignes the type `Set[A]` to the resulting value. 
When you create the set as `Set(new B("2"), new B("3"))` it assignes the type `Set[B]` to the resulting value.

Therefore, the resulting sets are different types and can not be intersected. But if you initialize your variables as follows:

```
val set12: Set[A] = Set(new A("1"), new A("2"))
val set23: Set[A] = Set(new B("2"), new B("3"))
```

then, you are assigning the types yourself. Since the resulting values have the same type, you are able to intersect and do the other operations.

For example, you can use `intersect` like the following:

```
val as: Set[A] = set12 intersect set23  // gives empty set as intersection
```

In the example above, the resulting intersection set is empty since they don't have the same objects.

To achieve successful comparison, you should also override the `equals` method of classes. In your case, it is enough to override only `A`.
Below is an unrecommended but working way (since extending case classes is not encouraged):

```
case class A(name: String) {
  override def equals(obj: scala.Any): Boolean = obj match {
    case A(x) => x.equals(name)
    case _ => false
  }
}

class B(name: String) extends A(name)

val set12: Set[A] = Set(new A("1"), new A("2"))
val set23: Set[A] = Set(new B("2"), new B("3"))

val as: Set[A] = set12 intersect set23  // gives A(2) as intersection
println(s"as = ${as}")
```

Comment: "But if you initialize your variables as follows:" I tried to write in my question this is something I cannot do. I need the set23 in other context where I need its B type.

Comment: "resulting intersection set is empty" You are correct, I have oversimplified the code. I have changed A to a case class - I know deriving from a case class is bad practice, but for the purpose of this question this is the shortest way how to make sure equals is overridden.

Comment: The `case class` example is just for the purpose of the question and it works for this purpose. I am sorry, but by extending how to properly override equals I am no closer to achieving my goal, the core part of the answer is still avoiding the question how to intersect two sets which need to be of different types.

Comment: After some research on your comment, I think that is not possible to compare two different types even if they have some covariant or contravariant relationship. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676615/why-is-scalas-immutable-set-not-covariant-in-its-type) for details.